# Circle are not always displayed in an svg element

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a web application in which I display a custom chart using d3.js.
Basically I have an array of values and I display it as a circle.

Here is the method I use :

```
function drawBandline(id, minValRange, maxValRange, data, width) {
    $("#" + id).empty();

    if (!isNaN(minValRange) && !isNaN(maxValRange)) {
        var height = 15, radius = 3, w_padding = 6;

        var svgContainer = d3.select("#" + id).append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (!isNaN(data[i])) {
                svgContainer.append("circle")
                    .attr("cx", adjustX(minValRange, maxValRange, data[i], width, w_padding))
                    .attr("val", data[i])
                    .attr("cy", 8)
                    .attr("r", radius)
                    .attr("fill", "#f93");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works well but sometimes some circles are not displayed in the SVG element while it is added to the SVG. If, for example, I minimize the window and then display it again, the circles are correctly displayed.

How can I fix that ? Thanks.

Comment: This app runs on Chromium

Comment: If the issue is visible only on Chromium, go raise a bug on Chromium's bugtracker (unless there already is one on this subject).